# Create a php date format using datestring

Tags: php, date

I  have a string like `2012-11-08`.

I want to convert this string into php date format with time too.

The output should be like

```
 $smv =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
 print $smv //  2012-11-08 16:05:56  (If we consider India )
```

I tried

```
$day = '2012-10-08';
echo = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($day));
```

But it is printing the date as `2012-10-08 00:00:00` (current time is not printed).

Comment: So you run some invalid PHP code and it actually produces an output?

Comment: You are entering day string but time is not there so it took '00:00:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
 $day = '2012-10-08'.date('H:i:s', time());
 echo  date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($day));
```

Comment: $year = '2012';
$month = '10';
$day = '08';

 $day = $year-$month-$day.date('H:i:s', time());
 echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($day));    printing 1994-11-08 11:54:23

Comment: $year = '2012';
$month = '10'; 
$day = '08'; 
$day = $year."-".$month."-".$day.date('H:i:s', time()); 
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($day));